# Serial port receives two more bytes than sent

Tags: c, serial-port

My setup is like this: An old Windows XP machine that still has a real serial port and a newer Windows 7 machine that uses a USB-Serial adapter. I'm trying to run the [librs232](https://github.com/ynezz/librs232) example which looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "librs232/rs232.h"

unsigned int err(unsigned int e);
unsigned int rs232_simple_test(void);

unsigned int err(unsigned int e)
{
    printf("%s (%s)\n", rs232_strerror(e), errno > 0 ? strerror(errno) : "");
    return e;
}

unsigned int rs232_simple_test(void)
{
    unsigned int try = 0;
    unsigned int bytes = 0;
    unsigned char data[1];
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    struct rs232_port_t *p = NULL;

    p = rs232_init();
    if (p == NULL)
        return 1;

#ifdef WIN32
    rs232_set_device(p, "COM1");
#else
    rs232_set_device(p, "/dev/ttyUSB0");
#endif
    ret = rs232_open(p);
    if (ret) {
        rs232_end(p);
        return err(ret);
    }

    rs232_set_baud(p, RS232_BAUD_9600);
    printf("[*] port settings: %s\n", rs232_to_string(p));

    rs232_flush(p);
    while (try++ < 10) {
        printf("%02d. [*] read: ", try);
        data[0] = 0x00;
        ret = rs232_read_timeout(p, data, 1, &bytes, 1000);
        if (ret)
            err(ret);
        else
            printf("0x%02x len: %d\n", data[0], bytes);

        data[0] = 0x05;
        bytes = 0;
        printf("%02d. [*] write: ", try);
        ret = rs232_write_timeout(p, data, 1, &bytes, 1000);
        if (ret)
            err(ret);
        else
            printf("len: %d\n", bytes);
    }

    rs232_end(p);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return rs232_simple_test();
}
```

This code sends the character 0x05 to COM1 ten times in a row. I run the test program on my Win7 machine. However, the output on the WinXP machine is this:

```
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x05
0x0500fc
```

You can see that in the last serial write operation there are suddenly two bytes more (0x00fc) than there should be. Why is that? Where do those two come from please? I don't understand that. Also, the output of the test program shown above clearly shows that only 1 byte is sent:

```
[*] port settings: device: COM1, baud: 9600, data bits: 8, parity: none, stop bits: 1, flow control: off
01. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
01. [*] write: len: 1
02. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
02. [*] write: len: 1
03. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
03. [*] write: len: 1
04. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
04. [*] write: len: 1
05. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
05. [*] write: len: 1
06. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
06. [*] write: len: 1
07. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
07. [*] write: len: 1
08. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
08. [*] write: len: 1
09. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
09. [*] write: len: 1
10. [*] read: timeout error (No such file or directory)
10. [*] write: len: 1
```

So why do 3 bytes arrive on the WinXP PC in the last write operation?

I have checked that baudrate, data bits, parity, flow control, and stop bits settings are identical on both machines and they also match the baud rate that is set in the code above (9600 baud) so I really have no clue what's wrong there. Anybody on here who can tell more please?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that is run on the WinXP side?

Comment: If you use a serial terminal program 8nstead of your receiving python, does it show the same data?

Comment: @zwol: I'm using a program called Serial Port Monitor on the WinXP side. Version 7.0, by Eltima.

Comment: @barny: Which program should I use on XP please?

Comment: Talk about spoon feeding... there is one built into pyserial, or go search using a well known search engine...

Comment: But I'm not using Python...

Comment: FWIW, I have now tried a different program on the XP side, namely HTerm, and the result is exactly the same. In the last cycle I get 0x0500fc although it should be just as 0x05 as before.

Comment: Sorry on the pyserial ref, that was a different question. Ok. So the answer to your question is: from the sending end. Prrhaps you are shutting down the transmitter serial port before it has finished transmitting? Eliminate variables - can you try a different serial port device? Make the transmitter wait 10s after the last write, ...

Comment: I don't really know this library but I wonder if the trailing `00 fc` is being generated by `rs232_end`.  Try adding a delay (`sleep(10)` maybe) right before that point.  Does anything change on the WinXP side?   I would also suggest writing a _different_ byte on each time through the loop, and making that byte be a printable ASCII character, e.g. `data[0] = 'A' + try;` to verify that you really are receiving all ten characters and none of them are being interpreted as controls somehow.

Comment: Weird, I uncommented some stuff in `rs232_end()` to see if the problem would go away and indeed it did go away but the weird thing is that now it is still working correctly although I am back at the *original* code now. Weird. So it's working now although I didn't change a thing. Not really satisfactory because I know the very same code didn't work earlier... but now I'm unable to reproduce the issue :/

Comment: Timing problems can do that. You should only close the serial port once you are sure it has completed sending the data you want to send.

Comment: the `0xFE` hints that there is a timing problem.